# Как вызвать model в файле библиоетки CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Я использую  Codeigniter.
Создал билиотеку Notice.php с кодом:

```
 class Notice {

          public $ci;

        public function __construct() {
             $CI = & get_instance();
             $CI->load->model('support_model');
             $this->ci = $CI;
         }

        public function sum_tickets()
        {

           $sum_tickets = $this->load->support_model->sum_tickets("0");
           return $sum_tickets;

      }
    }
```

Но функция не работает - я получаю ошибку:

> ERROR - 2017-12-02 16:39:05 --> Severity: Error --> Call to a member
>   function sum_tickets() on null application/libraries/Notice.php 18

Для views файла использую переменную `<?php echo $this->notice->sum_tickets(); ?>`

Как правильно использовать model функции в библиотеке и что я делаю не так?

Благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Правильная конструкция

```
class Notice
{

  function sum_tickets() {

      $CI =& get_instance();

      $CI->load->model('support_model');

      $tickets = $CI->load->support_model->sum_tickets("0");

      return $tickets;

  }
```